# Goose or Chilly Bumps or Pimples?

Tags: word-usage, slang

I've heard many people use the term "goose bumps"; in my family, they were "goose pimples," but I don't know if this was peculiar to us, or if others also use it.

My wife's family's saying for this was "Chilly bumps."

Are there others? Is one considered the "most correct"?

Comment: I've seen goose bumps used the most.

Comment: Since this is colloquial, whatever you were brought up with will sound 'most correct'; there really can be no other standard.

Comment: I prefer "Ganderbumps"! Viva las Mujeres!!!

Comment: http://www.theatlantic.com/health/archive/2013/06/pecan-caramel-crawfish-food-dialect-maps/276603/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The google (books and web) says that "goose bumps" (also one word, "goosebumps") is by far the more favored term over "goose pimples" or "goose flesh."  The technical terms for this phenomenon is cutis anserina, horripilation, or piloerection.

The google finds over 750K uses of "goose bumps" and only 124 of "chilly bumps."  I didn't look closely at the latter results, but I bet most of them are from your wife's family.

Comment: It should just be "Google," capitalized with no definite article. I think you should add some more to this answer, either an image of the results on Google, an explanation of what these Google numbers really mean (are they actual numbers, or estimates?), or a citation to a dictionary or other source.

Comment: "The google" is my pet term for the ubiquitous search engine.  The google probably wouldn't like it any better than you, and when they eventually come to run the world, they can talk me about it.  Nobody outside Google really knows what their search numbers mean, especially given the charges that they slant the results to favor their own content.  Anybody who asks a question here may perform the same search I did.  I take your point about dictionaries.

Comment: In Britain it always was, and I suspect largely remains *goose pimples*. And please no one quote me Google Ngrams. They now have the same status with me as Father Christmas. I have stopped believing in them. Who audits them?

Comment: @WS2 - In New England, (US) where many expressions  from the "mother country" still exist, it is "goose pimples".  (They also keep belongings in "cupboards" and call disappointments "a 'bloody' shame".

Answer (score 1):

The Ngram chart for "goose bumps" (blue line) versus "goosebumps" (red line) versus "goose pimples" (green line) versus "goosepimples" (yellow line) versus "goose flesh" (light blue line) versus "gooseflesh" (purple line) versus "chilly bumps" (no line because there were  too few matches) for the period 1840–2008 is interesting:

[image]

The most striking development shown in the chart is the precipitous rise of "goose bumps" from near zero to world domination between 1960 and 2005. From 1900 to 1930, "goose flesh"/"goose-flesh"/"gooseflesh" predominated; and from 1940 until the late 1970s, "goose pimples" ran a reasonably strong second. But the recent ascent of "goose bumps"/"goosebumps" makes these other trends look relatively minor.

William Safire, "[On Language: That Icy Tingle](https://www.nytimes.com/1982/11/07/magazine/on-language-that-icy-tingle.html)," in the *New York Times* (November 7, 1982) quotes a representative of the *Dictionary of American Regional English* as offering a very different hierarchy of usage:

> "**Goosepimples** is by far the most common response," reports Joan Hall, associate editor of *DARE*, the soon-to-be-published *Dictionary of American Regional English*, "with **goosebumps** being offered about half as frequently. **Gooseflesh** comes in a distant third." No geographic distinction shows itself, but older people tend to say *gooseflesh*, while younger people lean toward *goosebumps*, ...

But Ngram shows"goose bumps" and "gooseflesh" in a virtual tie for the most common form in works published in 1982, with "goose pimples" a distant third, only slightly ahead of "goosebumps."

As for alternative names for the condition, Safire offers a baker's dozen of options, presumably  culled from regional dictionary research:

> Lexicographic Irregulars across the country are going to read this and say, "Why, that city boy is talkin' about **chicken skin**. Or **duck bumps**, **thrill bumps**, **chilly bumps**, **turkey bumps**. Or he's fixin' to say he's **about to sprout feathers**. Or he's **got prickles**, **pins and needles**, **French knots**, **eggerbumps**, **ash spots**, **white measles** or **chill bugs**."

Comment: Impressive, thanks! I had forgotten about Ngram.